# Putting CSV data into a table in PyQt4

Tags: python, csv, pyqt, pyqt4

Currently I have a csv file which

```
with open('MY CSV FILE ', 'r') as csv:
                line = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
                for row in line:
                     print ",".join(row)
                     #IF I DO print(account) it will print the accounts into the SHELL,
```

How could I get each line into a table in pyqt4? Using a PyQt.QLabel somehow? the documentation on creating tables isn't very clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use PyQT Table Widget. You can specify the column in the Table Widget and after that you can set value to the cell of the table widget. You can use .setItem function to set the value

```
item = QTableWidgetItem()
item.setText("blah blah")
self.tableWidget.setItem(n, 0, item)
```

where n i row and 0 is column and item is the value.